# Is it possible to hold a list of react components in state and render them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been attempting to learn some React programming recently, and I ran into some confusion when learning about rendering lists.

The React documentation describes this method for rendering lists:

```
 const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <li>{number}</li>
  );
  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
```

Out of curiosity, I decided to try holding a list of React elements in the state of one of my components and render that list directly. I figured that it might be able to avoid the need of mapping the data to an element every time a render occurred.

I was able to make this work:

```
'use strict';

class List2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let nums = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            nums.push(React.createElement('div', null, i));
        }       

        this.state = {
            numbers : nums, 
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            React.createElement('div', null, this.state.numbers)
        )
    }
}
```

However, I tried to add a button to my window that added elements to the element list, the new elements added by the button's onCLick function don't render. This is the code that doesn't work:

```
'use strict';

class List3 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            nextNum : 1,
            numbers : [], 
        }

        this.buttonAction = this.buttonAction.bind(this);
    }

    buttonAction() {
        let numElement = React.createElement('h1', null, this.state.nextNum);

        let newNumber = this.state.numbers;
        newNumber.push(numElement);

        this.setState(
            { nextNum : (state.nextNum + 1),    
              numbers : newNumbers,
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            React.createElement('div', null, 
                this.state.numbers,
                React.createElement('button', {onClick : this.buttonAction}, 'clicketh')
            )
        )
    }
}
```

When I click the button, I don't see new numbers render on the screen.

Can someone help me explain what's going on here?
Is the mapping method from above the only reliable way to render lists with react?

Comment: React is data driven. Keep the data in the state and re-render whenever necessary.

Comment: While what you're doing is possible, the comment above me is correct; to elaborate @EmileBergeron comment further, one of react's strong points is that it encourages reusability (hence: components). And you should treat components as _state machines_, read more details here (and about what state should not contain): http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html ref: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1248.

Build react components rather than creating them on the fly. **The React Way**. The latter is like the jQuery way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React only renders those elements which got change from last render, If you want to force render then you have to force react to do it otherwise it will not render new elements.

Arrays are reference type so if will add or remove elements to it, it will not create a new copy and react will consider it as unchanged. 
For your render issue you need to create a new copy of "numbers" each time you add element so react will consider it as changed state and render as new.
you can achieve this by using map function in your render method which will provide react a new copy of array or use "slice" in your button click event so while setting new numbers state it will create a new shallow copy of "numbers" each time.

below are snippets for doing it in both ways.

```
buttonAction() {
    let numElement = React.createElement('h1', { key: this.state.nextNum }, 
    this.state.nextNum);

    let newNumbers = this.state.numbers;
    newNumbers.push(numElement);

    this.setState(
      {
        nextNum: (this.state.nextNum + 1),
        numbers: newNumbers.slice(),
      }
    );
  }
```

Or

```
  render() {
    return (
      React.createElement('div', null,
        this.state.numbers.map(item=>item),
        React.createElement('button', { onClick: this.buttonAction }, 'clicketh')
      )
    )
  }
```

for more info on array please follow below link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

Really not sure why you are doing this.

But maybe you can try something like this ?

```
this.setState({ 
   numbers :[...this.state.numbers, numElement],
});
```

Creating a copy of numbers instead of reusing the old reference.

Comment: I'm doing this purely for curiosities sake. I understand that the mapping method is the accepted method.

Comment: It did not. I got an error that state is not defined. There must be a binding issue with this.

Comment: try writing arrow function
`buttonAction = () => {`

Comment: This results in the same issue.